Search for a message using key or value
I would like find a published message using the message KEY or VALUE. How can I search the message and print it?
I have tried the below one but nothing is working:
def filter_messages(self, topic, key_filter=None,value_filter = None, timeout=10.0):

    try:
        # Get the list of partitions for the topic
        partitions = self.consumer.list_topics(topic).topics[topic].partitions
        # Create TopicPartition objects for all partitions
        topic_partitions = [TopicPartition(topic, p) for p in partitions]
        # Assign the consumer to all partitions
        self.consumer.assign(topic_partitions)

        while True:
            # Poll for a new message
            msg = self.consumer.poll(timeout=1.0)
            if msg is None:
                continue  # No new message within the poll interval
            if msg.error():
                if msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                    print("Reached end of partition.")
                    break  # Stop if reached the end of the partition
                else:
                    print(f"Error while consuming message: {msg.error()}")
                    continue

            # Decode the message key and value if present
            key = msg.key().decode('utf-8') if msg.key() else None
            value = msg.value().decode('utf-8') if msg.value() else None

            # Check if both key and value match the target criteria
            if key == key_filter and value == value_filter:
                print(f"Found matching message:\nKey: {key}\nValue: {value}")
                return  # Stop after printing the first match

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        self.consumer.close()


Clarify "nothing is working". You've not shown a [mcve]. What is self?


using the message KEY or VALUE

You'll want to use or, then rather than and
Otherwise, your code is correct and you'll need to debug your two filter parameters

You don't need python... Just use kafka-console-consumer and grep
